# Vectorization: Each row of the mask contains the column indices to mask for the corresponding row of the array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I have an array and a mask array. They have the same rows. Each row of the mask contains the indices to mask the array for the corresponding row. How to do the vectorization instead of using for loop?

Codes like this:

```py
a = np.zeros((2, 4))
mask = np.array([[2, 3], [0, 1]])

# I'd like a vectorized way to do this (because the rows and cols are large):
a[0, mask[0]] = 1
a[1, mask[1]] = 1
```

This is what I want to obtain:

```
array([[0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

==================================

The question has been answered by @mozway, but the efficiency between the for-loop solution and vectorized one is questioned by @AhmedAEK. So I did the efficiency comparison:

```py
N = 5000
M = 10000
a = np.zeros((N, M))

# choice without replacement
mask = np.random.rand(N, M).argpartition(3, axis=1)[:,:3]

def t1():
    for i in range(N):
        a[i, mask[i]] = 1
def t2():
    a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None], mask] = 1
```

Then I use `%timeit` in Jupyter and got this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
a[[[0],[1]], mask] = 1
```

Or, programmatically generating the rows slicer:

```
a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], mask] = 1
```

output:

```
array([[0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: just a small note, this answer is actually slower than the loop approach when `a` is bigger than (n,5000), due to how complex indexing and cache works ... so profiling is the best approach.

Comment: @AhmedAEK can you provide the code you used to test? But yes, in general it's best to compare approaches for each use case (which is undefined here)

Comment: @AhmedAEK Hi, thanks for the information. I did a little comparison and updated my question, pls check it. I believe the vectorization helps in my case.